# Spring boot with thymeleaf _csrf failing to initialize

Tags: java, authentication, spring-boot, thymeleaf, csrf

I am trying to setup a basic auth page with Spring (spring-boot).
When I disable CSRF protection the login works fine, but I get HTTP 405 for POST /login after authentication has complete. From my research it looks like that was because of CSRF was not enabled. I removed from my config `htto.csrf().disable()`, according to all docs and comments I've read I was expecting to see extra hidden field.

```html
 <input
                        type="hidden"
                        th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                        th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

That didn't happen. Then I added that manually, but I am getting an exception when Thymeleaf is parsing the template.

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'parameterName' cannot be found on null

Looks like _csrf is empty.

Here is what I have in gradle build.gradle:

> compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name:
>   'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
>       compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security')
>   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

This is my config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
UserRoleDetailService userDetailService;

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new InMemoryTokenStore();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/registration", "/error/access-denied", "/login**", "/logout").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").successForwardUrl("/admin/home").permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    http.userDetailsService(userDetailService);

}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Bean
public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}
}
```

Thymeleaf 3.0.9
Spring 5.0.4

What am I doing wrong here?
Any input appreciated! Thank you!

Update with HTML form

```html
            <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post" class="form-signin">
                <h3 class="form-signin-heading" th:text="Welcome"></h3>
                <br/>

                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" th:placeholder="Email"
                       class="form-control"/> <br/>
                <input type="password" th:placeholder="Password"
                       id="password" name="password" class="form-control"/> <br/>
                <input
                        type="hidden"
                        th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                        th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
                <div align="center" th:if="${param.error}">
                    <p style="font-size: 20; color: #FF1C19;">Email or Password invalid, please verify</p>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="Submit" value="Login" type="Submit"
                        th:text="Login"></button>
            </form>
```

Update #2

After tinkering with my code I figured that when I disabled the Resource server config the CSRF token started showing up as per documentation. Now the mystery is why having an OAuth2 resource server messes up with csrf being properly inserted?

Here is my Resource server config

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends 
ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private TokenStore tokenStore;

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
    resources.tokenStore(tokenStore);
    resources.resourceId(AuthorizationServerConfig.API_RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
}

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestMatchers()
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/users/**")
            .access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
            .and().exceptionHandling().
            accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
}

}
```

Comment: Can you show your Thymeleaf form code?

Comment: if you use the action attribute instead of th:action or method value to any of GET, HEAD, TRACE, or OPTIONS, then CSRF token won’t be inserted automatically.

Comment: I do have the th:action in my form ... See update. Th hidden csrf field is added manually here by me, but it didn't work with or without it.